# Can Resource Monitor include Hyper-V machines memory consumption in its results?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, memory, monitoring

Windows Resource Monitor is a nice (and built-in) tool providing a fast overview of resource utilization. On a server with Hyper-V installed, it correctly shows the CPU and disk activity generated by the virtual machines, but somehow they are excluded from the memory load statistics. Is there a way to include them?

Comment: There are free tools that monitor the CPU and disk for the hypervisor and all guests.  http://serverfault.com/questions/395473/hyper-v-cpu-utilization-good-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Performance Monitor has the information you want.  And, no, there's no way to modify the Resource Monitor to display what you want.

I also think that you're mistaken.  The CPU usage of guest VMs is not reflected in the Resource Monitor, though the disk usage is.

Comment: It's good to know Resource Monitor includes total disk usage, I thought I'd observed that, and it's good to confirm.  Any references?